# How to concatenate/join strings from a grouped column in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, string, join

Having

```
Company
id      Name
1       Enron
2       Walmart

Employee
id      Company
2       1
3       1
4       2
5       2
6       2
```

I want to get

```
Enron 2,3
Walmart 4,5,6
```

so far I wrote:

```
select Company.Name, Employee.id
from Company inner join Employee
on Company.id = Employee.Company 
group by Company.id
```

but the current result is

```
Enron 2
Walmart 4
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use [Group_Concat](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html):

```
select Company.Name, Group_Concat(Employee.id)
from Company inner join Employee
on Company.id = Employee.Company 
group by Company.id
```